# AWS AutoScaling Less and Big instances vs More and Small Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

AWS ECS autoscaling, we are using 6 of  c4.2xlarge
 instances for autoscaling group. 
Wondering is it a better idea to downgrade instance types and increase number of instances to 15

Answer (score 0):

There's no real answer to this. Some people may make a recommendation based on their experience, or tell you how to work it out yourself.

Smaller instances give you better granularity, which might slightly reduce your costs.

First thing to do is benchmark. That will help you work out what the constraining resource is - CPU, network bandwidth, disk bandwidth, memory, etc. How's the performance of the application on the different instance types? You might find a c4.large at half the price can do 3/4 the work of a c4.2xlarge. You might also try m4 instances, even an m3.medium. Based on that it could be cheaper to have smaller instances. It could also be the other way around, you might be better off with larger instances.

Comment: smaller instances come with limited network performance, we also need to consider this point right? If so having larger instances in autoscaling group would be better in term of performance?

Comment: It depends. You really need to benchmark. Your application could be network, CPU, or memory bottlenecked, until you benchmark you have no idea.